# jquery on hover per each div

Tags: jquery, hover, each

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3VB4b/
When I hover over the `.loop`, I want the `span.soc` in that div to fade. Right now, all of them are fading.

I've tried to use the `.each()` selector and no avail.

```
    <div class="loop">
    Content
    <span class="soc"> span</span>
</div>

<div class="loop">
    Content
    <span class="soc"> span</span>
</div>

<div class="loop">
    Content
    <span class="soc"> span</span>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".loop").hover(function() {
  $('span.soc').fadeTo("slow",100);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add 'this' to the context of your search to only find the child elements.

```
$(".loop").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('span.soc').fadeTo("slow",100);
});
```

Comment: `.find()` where were you? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You need to limit the selector to the children of the element being hovered over.  It's avaliable as `this` in the callback so try the following

```
$(".loop").hover(function() {
  $('span.soc', this).fadeTo("slow",100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

here you go (I also added the reverting back to the original state) : http://jsfiddle.net/3VB4b/2/

the code:

```
$(".loop").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('span.soc').fadeTo("slow",100);
}, function(){
    $(this).find('span.soc').fadeTo("slow",0.4);
});
```